# What sould the identical Linq to sql query for this sql server query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to convert Following sql server query with Linq-to-sql query . What I have to do. how it will be? I am using c#.

```
SELECT       Table1.CRNo, Table2.StageId

FROM         Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
             ON Table1.CRNo = Table2.CRNo

WHERE        (Table2.IsActive = 'true')
```

Table 1 and Table 2 are two tables. CRNo is identical in both tables. Table 2 is detail table of Table 1.

What should be the query.

**Edited**:

```
 from record1 in table1
 join record2 in table2 on record1.CRNo equals record2.CRNo
 where record2.IsActive
 select new { record1.CRNo, record2.StageId }
```

definitely, it is working fine. but results comes with a record who as IsActive False also if there are multiple entries in the table2. let say table 2 have records as :

```
CRNo:1 StageId: 1 IsActive:False
CRNo:2 StageId: 1 IsActive:False
CRNo:1 StageId: 2 IsActive:True
```

Then this is coming with CRNo 1 with Stage 1 , which has IsActive False. Why should this is happening ?
**Please review this again**

Comment: -1: What have you tried?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from record1 in table1
join record2 in table2 on record1.CRNo equals record2.CRNo
where record2.IsActive
select new { record1.CRNo, record2.StageId }
```

Comment: definitely, it is working fine. but results comes with a record who as IsActive False also if there are multiple entries in the table2. let say table 2 have records as CRNo:1 StageId: 1 IsActive:False | CRNo:2 StageId: 1 IsActive:False | CRNo:1 StageId: 2 IsActive:True Then this is comming with CRNo 1 with Stage 2 , which has IsActive False. Why should this is happenning ?

Comment: Because CRNo 1, StageId: 2 is active. If you want to only consider active entries in the query you have to filter first before doing the join. See edit in my post.

Comment: As Obalix says, CRNo 1, StageId 2 is active, that will be returned correctly. The other two records won't be returned because they're both not active. It's correctly filtering based on the IsActive flag :/

Comment: No, it isn't, at least not with that query given the information we have about your tables. That join is an inner join, returns the combination of all records where the CRNo matches. Those records where IsActive is false are then discarded, so that's both the Stage1's in your example. The only records returned, given the info so far, are those where record2.IsActive is true.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have a foreign key relationship present in you database - or modelled in your dbml - you could also do the following:

```
from t1 in Table1
where t1.Table2.IsActive == "true"   // assuming that IsActive is a string and not a boolean
select new { t1.CRNo, t1.Table2.StageId }
```

In order to speed up things you maybe should use `DataLoadOptions` to specify that for each `t1` the `Table2` entry should be fetched as well:

```
using (ctx = new MyDataContext()) {
  var options = new DataLoadOptions();
  options.LoadWith<Table1>(x => x.Table2);
  ctx.LoadOptions = options;

  var res = from t1 in Table1
            where t1.Table2.IsActive == "true"
            select new { t1.CRNo, t1.Table2.StageId };

}
```

Additionally you might want to [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) for samples of the linq syntax.

Edit - to consider only active entries:

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2.Where(x => x.IsActive == "true") on t1.CRNo equals t2.CRNo
select new { t1.CRNo, t2.StageNo };
```

Comment: According to LinqPad that second query generates the same SQL as it would if the where clause were part of the main query body...